# Alternative way to return the contents of the SQL Logs with TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Has anyone been able to work out another way to return the results of the SQL Server Logs. I know I can do it this way:

```
declare @sqlserverlogs table ( [LogDate] datetime, [ProcessInfo] varchar(10), 
    [Text] varchar(1000) )

select @start_date = (current_timestamp -1), @end_date = current_timestamp

insert into @sqlserverlogs exec sys.xp_readerrorlog 0, 1, '', '', 
    @start_date, @end_date, 'asc'

select * from @sqlserverlogs
```

The programme I am using needs a table returned from a single select statement. Is there another way to return the contents of the SQL Server Logs, like a table from a function or a view or any other way?

Cheers,
Adam

Comment: Can you explain why anything "needs" to be "a single select statement"? Your program can't call a single stored procedure?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of going through the xp, why not process this outside of SQL Server in general? The error logs are just plain text, so you could parse them with C# or PowerShell instead of T-SQL. This could allow you to filter first and then dump only the relevant rows to a table (or perhaps not use a table at all).

But it's hard to know why this has to be a single statement that looks like a table.

Comment: Good idea Aaron. The single select statement is because of the config file I'm using. It gets the sql statements and column headers from the file and then dynamically builds a table to allow people to customize their reports they are running by modifying the config file. I suspect I am going to have to code around it as you mentioned but i was hoping there were other TSQL options available.